# ABP Best practice to implementing gRPC

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Is there a way to best practice implementing grpc on this framework?
and is this also part of the framework? -> [Abp.Grpc](https://github.com/GameBelial/Abp.Grpc)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not part of the framework.
You should add the **abp** tag as well.